# Date, datediff and sum

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

Hi I have a table with following columns:

- ID (int)
- Start_Date (date)
- End_Date (date)

Table:

```
22/08/2000 - 23/08/2000
24/08/2000 - 28/08/2000
01/08/2000 - 29/08/2000
26/08/2000 - 30/08/2000

example...
24/08/2000 - 28/08/2000 ===>> 4 days
26/08/2000 - 30/08/2000 ===>> 4 days
```

sum ===>> 8 days, and i need get 6 because between 24/08/2001 and 30/08/2000 i have 6 and not 8, is that possible to do?

i want get all days of thousands of dates like in this picture: http://i947.photobucket.com/albums/ad316/danacarolinads/esa_zpsee1b4346.png

Comment: What is **your** definition of `BETWEEN`: do you include first and last days or not?

Comment: There is no rule in math or date algebra that I know of that states that the sum of two differences will equal the difference of the lowest of one difference and the highest of the other. For instance: `4 - 10 = 6; 5 - 12 = 7;` The sum of the differences is `13` the difference of the minimum and maximum, in this case `12 - 4` equals `8`, not `13`. So why do you assume the sum of your two date differences should be the same as the difference of `24/08/2000` and `30/08/2000`?

Comment: Also, your math is wrong as well. `24/08/2000 - 28/08/2000 = - 4 days`. But if you are getting just the difference, this would be the absolute value, which you should specify, since inverting either of the two you show `4 days` would get you a sum of 0.

Comment: And on a final note, if the expected difference is the dates between the given dates but not falling on the actual dates, you might get into some trouble as `24/08/2000 - 25/08/2000` and `24/08/2000 - 24/08/2000` would both be `0` days. This means that the sum of `24/08/2000 - 25/08/2000` and `22/08/2000 - 23/08/2000` would be `0`   `SUM(0, 0)` while your other assumption, that the sum should be the same as `25/08/2000 - 23/08/2000` would be `2` or `1` based on whether we're going on actual subtraction vs the "inside days".

Answer (score 0):

Can this approach your goal ?

```
SELECT MAX(End_Date) - MIN(Start_Date)
FROM MyTable
WHERE (Start_Date >= #2000-08-24# AND End_Date <= #2000-08-30#);
```

I've not checked the validity of the SQL string.

Comment: i want get all days of thousands of dates like in this picture: http://i947.photobucket.com/albums/ad316/danacarolinads/esa_zpsee1b4346.png